# Why is this code reading the filepath instead of the text inside the file?

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

Here's my readFromFile code:

```
private void readFromFile(String file) {
    String string = "";
    //reading   
    try{
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(filename); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){                
            string += line + "\n";
        }
        br.close(); 
        txaConversation.setText(string);
    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the "load button" in my dialog:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    int choice = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        readFromFile(filename);
        txaConversation.setText(filename);
    }
```

And in case you will be asking, here's the writeToFile code:

```
private void writeToFile(String filename) {
    try {
        String content = txaConversation.getText();
        File file = new File(filename);
        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And the "button save" code:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    int choice = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        txaConversation.setText(filename);
        writeToFile(filename);
    }
```

When I save it and open the text file from my computer, I can see the text. But when I load it using my program, it is showing me the file path.

Comment: `writeToFile(filename);` this line writes the file name into the file, so it makes sense that this is what the file will contain

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ips.readLine()` instead of `br.readLine()`

```
        int line;
        while ((line=ips.read())!=-1){                
            string += (char)line ;
        }
```

And no need of

```
    InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
```

Comment: `FileInputStream` also has a constructor that takes a String fileName as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that in your UI it shows the name of the file, and not the content?

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int choice = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    readFromFile(filename); // This reads the file content, but does not store it
    txaConversation.setText(filename); // Previous content of filename variable is the absolute path
}
```

Change the last two lines to the following, and you will instead show the content of the file

```
filename = readFromFile(filename);
txaConversation.setText(filename);
```

And also change your readFromFile method to the following

```
private String readFromFile(String file) {
    String string = "";
    //reading   
    try{
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(filename); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){                
            string += line + "\n";
        }
        br.close();
    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return string;
}
```

I would also strongly recommend that you look into the [finally-block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for resource handling